# Concatenating two verbs to describe a noun

Tags: verbs

I would like to say "Alive animals that arrive to Europe" and my attempt would be something like ヨロッパに着く生きている動物が.." but it seems kinda wrong to concatenate the two verbs in that way. I'm not sure if by simply changing 着く to 着いて would make any sense.

Thanks

Comment: 着る means "to put on/wear clothes".

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I meant 着く

Comment: In English, *alive* is a predicate-only adjective (*The animals are alive* but not *\*alive animals*), so you need to say *live* or *living* in attributive position (*Live animals* or *Living animals*).  Also, we *arrive at* rather than *\*arrive to*.  But did you mean something like *Animals that arrive in Europe alive* (= 'animals which are alive at the time they arrive in Europe')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Alive animals that arrive to Europe
>   ヨーロッパに着く生きている動物が..

Your attempt in Japanese somewhat makes sense, but not so good.

Google translation gives me as:
ヨーロッパに到着｛とうちゃく｝した生きている動物, but the expression isn't natural though it makes sense.

My attempt is as follows depending on the situation how the animals arrive to Europe:

> (1) 生きてヨーロッパに到着｛とうちゃく｝した動物 or 生きてヨーロッパに着｛つ｝いた動物
>   (2) 生きたままヨーロッパに到着した動物

In (1), the animals arrive to Europe after their making great effort such as swimming across the Atlantic Ocean.
On the other hand, in (2), these animals are very weak to be carried alive, so it was very lucky this time that they could carry them to Europe alive.